# Extensible Linux Cluster Operating System

Tags: linux, operating-systems, nfs, cluster

Assume I have a laptop(2 cores, 4G memory, 512G regular disk) running ubuntu and a desktop(4 cores, 16G memory, 512G ssd disk) with no operating system installed(i.e. a new suite of computing resources - disk space, memory, cpu processing power, etc).

I wonder if I can let my laptop "absorb"(the laptop is the interface for human-computer interaction; i.e. no input device for the desktop) the new computing resources. So basically, I'd like to see that, after the "absorb", suddenly in the system monitor on the laptop I'm seeing 6 cores, 20G mem, disk space becoming 1TB, run some application(e.g. firefox) and it gets much faster ... something like that.

And next time I buy another desktop, and it can be "absorbed" again by the two devices to form a more powerful "cluster".

I understand what I want sounds very similar to a cluster. Yes, I can set up a nfs and mpi to form a cluster. But in this case, when I open firefox on my laptop(note that the laptop is the only interface for human-computer interaction, no input device for the desktop), it's still going to run locally on the laptop; when I download more and more files the nfs server will get full again and how can I add more disk space on the fly with a new machine?

My understanding is, with a cluster, you can explicitly dispatch computational tasks(run a console program you wrote) to certain node(s); but here I'm really looking for a way to easily extend my computing capacity that can benefit me in daily use with newly-bought hardware - it's ok if I need to install a special version of OS(say, ABC gnu linux), just name it. The attitude is, ok laptop, you're my servant and you have some powerful desktops as your slaves. I don't care which slave you use, and don't ask me which slave I want to handle the work, just arrange the dispatch yourself and get the work done as quickly as possible. In more professional terms, I shouldn't specify in command which node is going to handle the task. Essentially and equivalently, I suddenly have a more power laptop, everything else being transparent to me as the user.

Maybe I haven't fully understood the essence of mpi clustering - please point out if I actually can achieve what I want with MPI clustering.

Please enlighten me, thanks.

Comment: I used to make Beowulf clusters with Slackware Linux on a bunch of old hardware sitting around "just for fun", so it's absolutely possible ... but this also required some dedicated interconnects (e.g. I was lucky enough to have fiber cards at my disposal). The bottle neck is how they connect to each other to share the data. What you want is completely possible to the average home user, but unless you have a really fast connection on the cluster, you could actually see a performance LOSS (WiFi and CAT5 aren't fast enough to push the amounts of data you're wanting to push).

Comment: @txtechhelp Thanks for the reply. On the connection side, I have a modem/router 2 in 1 and the devices are supposed to be connected by wire via the modem/router. It may still be a bit slow, I totally agree. But let's disregard the speed for a minute. How did you make it work? Did you just install nfs for file sharing(if yes, how did you make it scalable with newly added hardware? I don't want a central nfs server)? Did you have to manually specify in command which node should handle the application?(this manual "load balancing" is also something I want to get rid of). Cheers.

Comment: Also, my laptop has less than 5% disk space left. I start to worry that with the nfs approach, performance will start to suck even if the external nfs is huge - after all, my laptop has its own OS, and I'm sure nfs is treated differently than its own hard disk(to name one, I don't think OS would use nfs as virtual memory/swap space, etc; basically, its own disk space can't be easily extended simply by nfs) - That's also something I want to overcome: I need a cluster where disk/memory/cores are truly shared, to a more-or-less equivalent extent.

Comment: If the speed of the cluster isn't a concern then I'd recommend doing some reading on [how to setup a linux cluster](http://www.linux.org/threads/building-a-linux-cluster.7858/); it's not terribly complicated, but does require getting your hands dirty with custom scripts/installs. Essentially though you'd be "starting from scratch" (fresh install on both machines to make them part of the cluster) as "upgrading" either of them won't necessarily work (though you might find some guides to help you there too) ..

Comment: A `how to` would be too broad a Q&A for this forum and essentially I'd be just rewriting what other tutorials have in them. But after you've got the bulk of it started or have done some more research as to what you would do for your specific situation (i.e. what distro to use, an initial setup, configs/etc.), I/the SU community can answer more to guide/help in the process

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's not too different from a post I saw about setting up the cluster using the same mpich1. I'll buy a machine and give it a go. Will post back if there're problems. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

What are you using this for? This is a huge topic.

Let's keep pure GUI components out of the equation, because for those the resources involved are different from memory and cpu (Human-computer interfaces, GPU), and cannot really be distributed (of course you can distributed your GPU for big processing loads, but let's leave that use case out of the equation for now).

Let's talk about server applications (and going back to my previous question, even something user oriented like emacs can be run with a server backend).

You could create a Kubernetes Cluster so that you are basically able to schedule anything you want anywhere on the cluster. Kubernetes will run any docker image, allocating intelligently, so the limit is the sky.
So with this you have already distributed your CPU and RAM.

Now to the issue of more persistent state. Where are the files? Where is the data?

You could go about this in many, MANY different ways.

You should start by having a distributed file system (or distributed block storage). A "proper" one. In this category the only star seems to be LizardFS. I'd stay away from Ceph.

Anybody, from anywhere, wherever kubernetes allocates, can access the lizardfs endpoint.

If you are running a database, of course you can run the database clustered. Where do the database instances forming the cluster ultimately save the data? One of two places I'd say:

1. The database instances forming the database cluster are just docker containers, allocated like any other docker image by kubernetes (with the constraint of course of only having one per physical node), and can use **local disk** wherever they are allocated ([currently not a Persistent Volume](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7562/)).
2. Kubernetes provides a zillion types of Persistent Volumes, which will be accessible from the database instances running on the cluster.

Note that the providers themselves can run as Kubernetes workloads, one per physical machine. When doing so they use local disk resources and make it available to the entire cluster.

LizardFS  is sadly currently not included, however you can expose LizardFS as an NFS endpoint and use that from the Kubernetes Cluster (I haven't seen anybody doing that yet, if you see any links please share.)

it can use the distributed file storage itself (this might be slower, there are "two levels of indirection").

Note that distribution in the case of storage can achieve two things:
- HA the fact that you have multiple copies of the data means that if one copy is unavailable you continue churning.
- Horizontal scaling. Basically data is sharded and allocated to different nodes. (each shard can potentially run in HA).

There are of course hybrid modes, and it all really boils down to make compromises within the CAP theorem. 
It's complex problem.
For instance see how [Arango does it](https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/cluster/).

Examples of databases include:

- Janusgraph with the Cassandra Backend
- ArangoDB
- OrientDB

Relational databases have their HA setups that you can run of course on K8S. For HA/sharding all-in-one setups ala ArangoDB, well it's not that easy anymore.

Other technologies you might find interesting. A "what I want to run on my local network when I become a **real** man" list :-). Note these have higher hardware requirements, more nodes more total RAM etc.

- Docker Swarm
- CoreOS
- Openstack
- DCOS
- Openshift
- Fabric8

PS: and yes you could run an X server on a scheduled K8S container.... Now I don't want to think about it as I have enough on my mind with the server side. I am sure there are enough people out there who have nothing better to do who run x servers in Kubernetes...
PS2: Unfortunately I only have enough reputation for 2 links but all the keywowrds are googable rather easily.